# How to get the Apex Character Limit via Api/SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, api, limits

basically trying to grab this metric, without having to go into salesforce?

[image: ApexClass]

Had a look at /services/data/vxx.x/limits

Didnt see it here.

Also looked at tooling api and whats available via
/services/data/vxx.x/

Didnt see it available.

Comment: select count(Id) ,  sum(LengthWithoutComments ) from ApexClass where NamespacePrefix = ''
Can kinda do this but it doesnt exclude test classes.

Comment: See related question to get this data via SOQL - [Query Code Used Limit (Total Characters)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/158011/102)

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger we still dont have the character limit for the org listed anywhere, 
ie. 6,000,000 

If i were to execute SELECT  SUM(LengthWithoutComments) FROM ApexClass where NamespacePrefix = '' 

This would still include test classes, which dont included in the calculation for apex code

Answer (score 1):

That bit of limit is not exposed as an API at the moment.  If you really want to get it, you could screen scrape that page. We have implemented screen-scrapping in few places (like to get list of Metadata Deployments or Download Report as a whole) and it has worked fine for us.

To screen-scrape, you would need to first get session id, then login to Salesforce using [frontdoor.jsp](https://company.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00D634f209252255TW!alfjsalfdkjasdflskdjfd.askdfasdlfjsdalskdf&retURL=), which should return cookies. Next time, goto Apex Classes page and extract the text.

Comment: Yeah, thought as much that it wasnt exposed.
I'll have read a bit about screen scraping to understand more and put out a idea to salesforce.